# Jquery Scroll to bottom in Firefox AND Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

```
function run_battle() {

if(battlenow.length>0) { 
var div = document.getElementById('show_battle');
    $("#show_battle").animate({ scrollTop: $("#show_battle").prop("scrollHeight") -       $('#show_battle').height() }, 100);
var attempt = battlenow.shift(); 
div.innerHTML += attempt;
    $("#show_battle").animate({ scrollTop: $("#show_battle").prop("scrollHeight") - $('#show_battle').height() }, 100);
setTimeout("run_battle()",800);
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far. It works great in firefox. Yet in Chrome, it doesn't work at all. I'm using Jquery 1.7.1, So that's why I'm using .prop instead of .attr.

The battlenow array is like this.

```
battlenow.push('Alan hit Joe<br><br>');
battlenow.push('Joe fainted<br><br>Battle Over');
```

If that helps any.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that I use that works in all browsers to scroll to a particular element. This code scrolls the minimal amount to get the element on screen, you might want something different. Note the check for webkit browsers:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.scrollMinimal = function() {

    var cTop = this.offset().top;
    var cHeight = this.outerHeight(true);
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var visibleHeight = $(window).height();

    if (cTop < windowTop) {
      $(jQuery.browser.webkit ? "body": "html")
        .animate({'scrollTop': cTop}, 'slow', 'swing');
    } else if (cTop + cHeight > windowTop + visibleHeight) {
      $(jQuery.browser.webkit ? "body": "html")
        .animate({'scrollTop': cTop - visibleHeight + cHeight}, 'slow', 'swing');
    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```

Called like:

```
$('#actions').scrollMinimal();
```

Comment: I've tried that already. My "show_battle" div is inside another div. When I use that code, it scrolls the parent div and not the one I want.

Comment: I use this for a chat window to scroll to the last message which is a div inside of a div, so that definitely works. I guess I don't understand what you're seeing. If you want to get to the bottom of a div, you can create a placeholder div immediately after the target one and then scroll to the placeholder div instead.

Comment: My main content div, that holds the show_battle div. I turned off the overflow:auto; on it and now it works. :)